# read csv in r, in which one of the column has english sentences and can have "

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv with `sep='\t'`. When I try to read the csv using the following code, not all the rows are read.

```
data <- read.csv("raw.txt", sep='\t', header=T)
```

Most likely the reason being, the data has " (quote) in its text. How to read such a file?

Format of file is:

```
text           freq
he is "Sam"    45
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data <- read.csv("raw.txt", sep='\t', header=T,quote="")
```